# Kotlin measureTime differs from kotlinx-benchmark (jmh) by far

Tags: kotlin, jmh

I'm testing with the following class (You can find a git repository [here](https://github.com/tobi6112/stackoverflow-slow-benchmark)):

```kotlin
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
class TestBenchmark {

    private fun benchmark() : List<Int> {
        return buildList {
            addAll(0..100)
            shuffle()
            sortDescending()
        }
    }

    final fun measureTime() {
        val result: Any?
        val time = measureNanoTime {
            result = benchmark()
        }
        println("$time ns")
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SampleTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    final fun benchmarkFunction() {
        benchmark()
    }
}

@ExperimentalStdlibApi
fun main() {
    TestBenchmark().measureTime()
}
```

With kotlins `measureTimeNanos` I get `65238400 ns` on my machine. However when performing a benchmark with kotlinx-benchmark via `gradlew benchmark` I get:

```
  Success: N = 611869
  mean =  12388,465 ±(99.9%) 39,959 ns/op
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Avoiding Benchmarking Pitfalls on the JVM : https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-benchmarking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't use `measureNanoTime` for microbenchmarks like this: that result is completely unreliable. A big reason for that are optimizations made at runtime by the JVM, as well as non-deterministic behavior like GC or system effects like power management, OS scheduling, and time sharing.

The entire point of JMH is to create a harness which attempts to work around all of these issues, to produce more reliable micro-benchmarking results.

See the article [Avoiding Benchmarking Pitfalls on the JVM](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-benchmarking.html) for a deeper discussion of the issues.

Aleksey Shipilëv, one of the maintainers of JMH, has many fascinating articles and talks about the subject. See:

- https://shipilev.net/#benchmarking ("Two Timestamps" Story)
- https://shipilev.net/#benchmarking-1 ("The Lesser of Two Evils" Story)

See also: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).